# C++ thread network priorities

Tags: c++, multithreading, networking, c++11

Is there any way to set a specific std::thread's network usage priority levels? E.g. I have multiple threads downloading information, but not all of them should have the same network usage, as I want some of the threads to download specific information faster.

Comment: In general there is no such thing as a 'thread network priority'.

Comment: The exact solution to your issue is implementation specific.  If I were you, I would use a network manager with a dedicated thread, and each thread trying to write would get its own buffer into which it dumped data.  This operation could maybe block until the buffer empties (kind-of-synchronously), or until the data is fully sent (asynchronously).  In either case, the network manager would allocate network resources to the waiting data for threads as it sees fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a threading issue and should not be dealt with a the thread level. Instead, you should somehow specify when initiating each download how prioritized it is. How to do that depends entirely on how you are doing the downloads and what (if any) quality of service services you have available in the network.

Comment: Guess you are right, I've been using libcurl for the requests, but haven't found a way to increase a specific handle's priority over others'. Need to re-think the solution a bit, but was worth a try, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You could set the respective socket receive buffer sizes according to the priority, making sure that only the highest-priority ones have a socket buffer >= the bandwidth-delay product.